# mySQL Update field to delete everything that comes after a substring

Tags: mysql

need to update a full column to delete everything that comes after a certain substring. Is this possible in mySQL?
Have a product table with id, name, price, category, etc and in the Name column after the product's name there is a substring that starts with:
Retail ...
I need to update all my rows to delete that substring (Retail...) I first try with REPLACE but after Retail everything its always different.
thanks

Comment: 1) Schema and sample data 2) http://sqlfiddle.com demo 3) Desired result 4) What have you tried so far? This should be primer before post any SQL-related question

Comment: You'll asking: Can I update a column and then delete everything after a particular substring? What do you mean by the second part of this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for was SUBSTRING_INDEX http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index
thanks